# Ideas for how to attach meta data to an arbitrary sprite sheet?

Tags: 2d, sprites, monogame, spritesheet, json

I am currently messing around with monogame and creating some silly sprite based games. One issue I have is when I get sprites for OpenGameArt or any equivalent they are often in spritesheets in a rather random manner.

For me to parse these spritesheets and actually get the specific sprites, (coordinates on spritesheet, attach them if they are animations, width, height etc), have proven to be a fairly laborous task. Which basically means I have to manually go through each sprite sheet, assign it the relative coordinate in a json file with  all the other meta data. This obviously takes forever and is not a very nice workflow.

So I was wondering is there any sort of way for me to at least detect sprites in a spritesheet? and output those coordinates to a json file? I have been looking around and I cannot really find much of anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easier way to get sprites from a spritesheet](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151024/is-there-an-easier-way-to-get-sprites-from-a-spritesheet)